# Why is the function defined in an 'if' condition's expression part not visible outside?

Tags: javascript

```
if (function f() {}) {
    console.log(f) // Throw an error: f is not defined
}
```

Why will the log cause an error, the `f` isn't already defined in the above expression?

---

You'd expect this is equivalent to:

```
function f () {}
if (true) {
    console.log(f); // Throw an error: f is not defined
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd declare a function in an `if` statement, if you declare `var f = function() {}` above it, it will work just fine.

Comment: Additionally, if you do `if(f = function() {})` it works just fine.

Comment: There seems to be confusion about block scope vs function scope but I don't think that is relevant. I suggested an edit.

Comment: @Doge, your edit confuses the point.  You are declaring a variable f as a function.  Which is different than declaring a function. As numerous people have stated, `if(f = function() {}) ` Works... because it stores the function in a global variable.

Comment: `function f(){}` is equivalent to `var f = function () {}` assuming certain constraints. What do you think the original code is equivalent to?

Comment: @Doge It not equivalent to anything that's declared outside of the wrapper. That's the problem. As I said, when you assign the function to a global variable, it exists.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you say

```
function f () {}
```

It is a function declaration statement. This function will be defined in the enclosing environment. So, if it is defined inside another function, then the function will be defined within that environment, where you can access this function by name.

But, when you use the function declaration in an expression, it will not be treated as Function Declaration, but *Function Expression* and that will be evaluated like this (Quoting from [ECMA Script 5.1 Standard Specification](http://es5.github.io/#x13))

> #### [13 Function Definition: Semantics](http://es5.github.io/#x13)
>
> The production
>
> FunctionExpression :
>
> ```
>  function Identifier ( FormalParameterListopt ) { FunctionBody }
> ```
>
> is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let **funcEnv be the result of calling [NewDeclarativeEnvironment](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.2.2)** passing the running execution context’s [Lexical Environment](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2) as the argument
> 2. Let envRec be funcEnv’s environment record.
> 3. Call the **[CreateImmutableBinding](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1.1.7)(N) concrete method of envRec passing the String value of Identifier** as the argument.
> 4. Let closure be the result of creating a new Function object as specified in 13.2 with parameters specified by FormalParameterListopt and body specified by [FunctionBody](http://es5.github.io/#x13). Pass in funcEnv as the Scope. Pass in `true` as the Strict flag if the FunctionExpression is contained in [strict code](http://es5.github.io/#x10.1.1) or if its FunctionBody is strict code.
> 5. Call the **[InitializeImmutableBinding](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1.1.8)(N, V) concrete method of envRec passing the String value of Identifier and closure** as the arguments.
> 6. Return closure.

So, when you create a function in an expression,

1. a new environment context will be created (see first item)
2. the function's name will be bound to the newly created environment (see the third item).
3. The function body will be used to create the actual function object (see the fourth item)
4. The actual function object created is bound to the function's name in the newly created context (see the fifth item)
5. Then the function object is returned.

It is up to the program to assign the function object to variable in the current environment context to retain the function. Otherwise, when the expression evaluation is done, the newly created environment context becomes invalid. So, the function `f` will not be visible outside.

Comment: Awesome explanation of one of the more subtle JS (arguably) bad parts.

Comment: @mjhm why bad? Make an argument for that the current behavior when a named function expression is used is suboptimal. Normally, when you use a named function expression, it's a recursive immediately invoked function expression. These don't need to be visible in their surrounding scope.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak. I bias strongly toward code clarity over micro-optimization or scoping purity in JS programming.  That's just me.

Answer (score 7):

Your assumption is incorrect. Those two snippets are not equivalent. The first is a [*named function expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression) where you don't store the value (the actual function object). Such an object is always truthy - and thus the `if` get's executed.

The function name for those functions is (or rather should be) only visible *inside* the function itself (except for some early IE versions). So, because `f` simply does not exist, a `ReferenceError` is thrown when you try to pass it to `console.log`.

Comment: Your explanation and the link explain the matter very well IMO. I even tried it because the question itself was really interesting. http://jsbin.com/silay/1/edit - the name 'factorial' is visible only in the function body.

Comment: Most likely `f` is a reference error and `console.log ` doesn't even get called; of course, `console.log` can log `undefined` just fine

Comment: Why does it behave like a named function?  I thought named functions are supposed to be assigned like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/gZqay/

Comment: @Smeegs The placement (as the if-condition) makes it an expression and not a declaration. The *name* in *named function expression* is not from the variable-name but rather from the name of the function. Which is not visible outside the function itself.

Comment: Gotcha, which is why the function isn't ever declared.  It evaluates the function declaration, but doesn't actually declare the function (outside of the function itself).

Answer (score 4):

Function declaration statements define a function in their surrounding scope and even move the definition to the top. This is, however, a named function expression. The function is defined by its name inside of it, but not outside (except in old IE, where it's a bug). Outside of it, it's just a function that has its name set. Only if the statement starts with the keyword `function`, it counts as a function statement.

This works:

```
function f(){};
if (f) console.log(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (function f() {}) {
    console.log(f) // Throw an error: f is not defined
}
```

The function declaration is considered as a function expression (like function (){} ), not a function statement.

Proof:

```
if (function f(x) {return x}(1)) {
    console.log('foo'); //Will log
}

if (function f(x) {return x}(false)) {
    console.log('foo'); //Will not log
}
```

If your function was trully a statement you could not execute it right away (without wrapping it in parentheses or prefixing it with a `!` to turn it into an expression).

```
function f(x) {return x}(false) //Would yield a syntax error
```

Comment: The condition is now false, so nothing gets printed. This does not explain why `f` is not available in the `if` statement.

Comment: Wow. This was a radical edit. Was it one of the other answers that changed your mind? :-)

Comment: no, i just wanted to get to the bottom of this issue,that's all.So i checked the spec.

Comment: @mpm: Excelllent illustration when it comes to the difference b/w statement & expression. However the last line didn't yield a syntax error in my case(Google Chrome).